# Ожидание ответа от устройства. Состояние гонки

Tags: c#, .net, timeout, race-condition

Есть устройство, которое по com-порту периодически шлет пакеты. Так же устройству можно послать команду, на которую он должен ответить подтверждением.

Я хочу реализовать блокирующий метод передачи команды, который вернет управление, когда будет получен ответ, либо выбросит исключение, если истечет время ожидания.

Поскольку устройство само периодически шлет сообщения, которые нужно отправлять, то в отдельном потоке идет прием данных и после приема всего пакета генерируется событие приема пакета. Структура такая:

```
    Frame lastTxFrame; // последняя отправленная команда

    // Отправить пакет и дождаться ответа или таймаута  
    void Send(Frame frame)
    {
        lastTxFrame = frame;
        serialPort.Write(frame);

        /* заблокировать поток, дождаться ответа или таймаута */
    }

    // Принято сообщение
    void OnFrameReceived(object sender, Frame rxFrame)
    {
        if(lastTxFrame != null && IsReply(lastTxFrame, rxFrame))
        {
            /* разблокировать поток, ожидающий ответ */
        }
    }

    // Проверить является ли сообщение reply ответом на команду command
    bool IsReply(Frame command, Frame reply)
    {
        return true;
    }
```

Как можно реализовать этот алгоритм, что бы не было гонки потоков?
Можно после отправки пакета запустить таймер, а в методе обратного вызова детектировать таймаут, а если пришел пакет, то останавливать таймер. Но в описании System.Threading.Timer сказано, что после вызова Dispose может произойти вызов callback'а. Значит теоретически мы можем и получить ответ и словить таймаут.

Можно использовать Interlocked-методы для определения был ли вызван колбэк таймера или обработчик приема сообщения:

```
    int timeout = 0;

    void OnFrameReceived(object sender, Frame rxFrame)
    {
        if(Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref timeout, 1, 0) == 0) // таймаута не было
        {

        }
    }

    void TimerCallback(object state)
    {
        if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref timeout, 2, 0) == 0) // таймаут
        {

        }
    }
```

Но в таком случае непонятно как сбросить переменную timeout в первоначальное значение, для отправки следующего сообщения.

Как корректно реализовать ожидание?

Comment: на ум приходит очередь команд, которые обрабатываются одним потоком

Comment: самый простой вариант - в одном потоке вести и прием данных и опрос очереди сообщений на отправку. Но хочется разобраться именно с синхронизацией. Кажется, что подобные задачи встречаются очень часто и должно быть какое-то протоптанное решение.

Comment: если `Send` будет однопоточным, то это легко можно реализвать через [ManualResetEvent](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.manualresetevent?view=netframework-4.7.2) или [ManualResetEventSlim](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.manualreseteventslim?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Comment: @Vasek Интересен общий случай, когда несколько потоков вызывают Send(frame), пакеты складываются в общую очередь и потоки блокируются, а затем по одному разблокируются, когда получен ответ на соответстующую команду или после наступления таймаута.   Но даже если пакет отправляет только один поток, то как избавиться от гонки? В методе Send мы вызываем mre.WaitOne(timeout), но всё-равно имеем гонку: если ManualResetEvent вернет управление по таймауту, а в потоке чтения мы получили ответ на команду, то детектируем и таймаут и получение ответа.

Comment: В протоколе есть некий query_id? Если нет, то как предполагается различать ответы для двух ожидающих `Send`?

Comment: @Vasek Да, можно определить на какой запрос был получен ответ, но это уже детали реализации, вопрос более общий - как организовать синхронизацию потоков?

Comment: Ну если в общем, то... Можно завесит словарь(ConcurrentDictionary) ключом у которого будет уникальный признак запроса, а значении будет ManualResetEvent. `Send` создает ManualResetEvent кладет его в словарь и ждет, после ожидания(неважно удачного или нет) он его из словаря удаляет. Читатель когда получает пакет пытается из словаря забрать(не удаляя) эвент и если получается взводит его, иначе просто пропускает пакет. Но это в общем)) На практике все может быть сложнее.

Comment: @Vasek а как атомарно отправить пакет и вызвать ManualResetEvent.WaitOne()? Ведь если после отправки пакета и до вызова WaitOne(), поток может быть вытеснен, а в это время придет ответ от устройста

Comment: Нужно заносить запись в словарь до отправки и тогда все будет хорошо. Если вариант со словарем устраивает я могу написать ответ.

Comment: @Vasek Давай максимально упростим: есть всего два потока - 
первый, который ожидает сообщение и вызывает вызывает событие (OnFrameReceived(sender, frame)), второй - который вызывать метод метод Send(frame). Метод Send должен быть блокирующим и возвращать управление придет ответное сообщение или по таймауту.